# How do I get a reference stored in a struct with the reference's original lifetime?

Tags: rust

I am trying to run the following code. It was straightforward to understand that the lifetime of the returned value of `inner()` was not compatible with the `'static` lifetime, but how can I make this work without changing the `main()` function?

```
struct Wrapper<'a>(&'a str);

impl<'a> Wrapper<'a> {
    fn inner(&self) -> &str {
        self.0
    }
}

pub fn main() {
    let x = "hello";
    let wrapper = Wrapper(&x);
    let _: &'static str = wrapper.inner();
}
```

```
error[E0597]: `wrapper` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:12:27
   |
12 |     let _: &'static str = wrapper.inner();
   |                           ^^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
13 | }
   | - borrowed value only lives until here
   |
   = note: borrowed value must be valid for the static lifetime...
```

I came across this as a example from a course I am following but I am kind of stuck with understanding how to make this work.

Answer (score 3):

All you have to do is change the signature of `inner` so that the return type matches the type of the `Wrapper`'s field:

```
impl<'a> Wrapper<'a> {
    fn inner(&self) -> &'a str {
        //              ^^ 'a added here
        self.0
    }
}
```

When you initialize the variable `wrapper` with `Wrapper(&x)`, the compiler infers that its type is `Wrapper<'static>`, because `x` has the `'static` lifetime (all literal strings have the `'static` lifetime). Thus, when you call `inner` on a `Wrapper<'static>`, the return type is `&'static str`.

If we don't add `'a` to the signature, then the lifetime of the returned value is the lifetime of the `Wrapper` itself. This is more apparent if we write out the lifetimes in full:

```
impl<'a> Wrapper<'a> {
    fn inner<'b>(&'b self) -> &'b str {
        self.0
    }
}
```

Your `Wrapper` doesn't have the `'static` lifetime because it lives in a local variable; its life will end when the function returns — `main` isn't special when it comes to lifetimes. Therefore, the returned string slice doesn't have the `'static` lifetime either.

Now, maybe you're wondering, *"If the original string has the `'static` lifetime, why is it valid to return it with a different lifetime?"*. It's important to understand that lifetimes don't have to be exact; they can be shortened if necessary. The goal of lifetimes is to ensure you don't use a reference after its referent has been dropped; if you claim that a value has a lifetime shorter than it's actually is, it's totally safe, it just (perhaps unnecessarily) restricts how long the reference can be used.

Comment: Thanks Francis, this makes things more clear for me.